# Qt: Undefined reference to 'vtable for MyClass'

Tags: c++, qt

I am using Qt Creator for my project. When I try to run the code below, verbatim, I get a compiler error `undefined reference to 'vtable for MyClass'`. I have looked around and apparently that is the compiler's way of saying there is a missing implementation of a virtual function.

In myclass.h:

```
class MyClass : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT

 public:
  MyClass(QTimer* timer) {}
  virtual ~MyClass() {}
};
```

In main.cc:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QTimer timer;
  MyClass myclass(&timer);
  return app.exec();
}
```

I cannot tell what I am doing wrong..

Comment: From the Build menu -> Clean All, Run qmake, Rebuild all

Answer (score 1):

You need to run qmake. Just clicking build won't run qmake again

qmake runs moc which generates .cpp & .h based on your .ui files. Those files are not lined up properly with the rest of your project because they were not updated. It is good to remember that if you had ever changed your ui, remember to run qmake.

For more detail on vtable and what their function is: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table